# Fit theoretical dartboard in image containing dartboard

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following image containing a dartboard

[image]

After processing the image looks as follows:

[image]

In addition, I have a function that creates a theoretical dartboard:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def draw_dartboard():
        IMG = np.ones((400, 400), 'uint8') * 255
        center = (int(IMG.shape[0] // 2), int(IMG.shape[1] // 2))
        size_dartboard = int(340)
        r_board = int(170)
        r_db = int(6.35)
        r_sb = int(15.9)
        r_doubles = int(162)
        r_triples = int(99)
        width_rings = int(8)

        cv2.circle(IMG, center, r_doubles + width_rings, (0,0,0), -1)
        cv2.circle(IMG, center, r_doubles, (255,255,255), -1)
        cv2.circle(IMG, center, r_triples + width_rings, (0,0,0), -1)
        cv2.circle(IMG, center, r_triples, (255,255,255), -1)
        
        thetas_min = np.radians([(18 * t - 9) for t in range(20)])
        thetas_max = np.radians([(18 * t + 9) for t in range(20)])
        
        for idx, (theta_min, theta_max) in enumerate(zip(thetas_min, thetas_max)):            
            if (idx % 2) == 0: 
                x_min = int(center[0] + r_board * np.cos(theta_min))
                y_min = int(center[1] + r_board * np.sin(theta_min))
                x_max = int(center[0] + r_board * np.cos(theta_max))
                y_max = int(center[1] + r_board * np.sin(theta_max))
                cv2.fillPoly(IMG, np.array([(center, (x_min,y_min), (x_max,y_max))]), (0,0,0))
           
        cv2.circle(IMG, center, r_sb, (0,0,0), -1)
        
        return IMG
```

The output of this image looks as follows:

[image]

How can I “fit” the theoretical dartboard in the real image? Clearly, there is a mismatch in orientation and scale. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Since the real image orientation and perspective is different, you need to warp its perspective. wapPerspectie function can be used to do it, and you may use minAreaRect to get the inmput parameters for waprPerspective

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/fit-theoretical-dartboard-in-image-containing-dartboard/7123

Comment: Can you post the code you used to process the image?

Comment: And please post the raw image you used to process.

Comment: Finally, can you post the processed image directly, by first using `cv2.imwrite("processed.png", processed_img)`, and uploading the output?

Answer (score 4):

You can *register* your dartboard image (i.e. source image) to the one you processed (i.e. destination image) by using [affine transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d61/tutorial_warp_affine.html).

Here is my approach, and the outcome.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# read images and remove matplotlib axes
src = cv2.imread('source.png',0)
src = src[20:-30,40:-20]

dest = cv2.imread('dest.png',0)
dest = dest[40:-40,40:-40]

# find matching points manually
dest_pts = np.array([[103,29],[215,13],[236,125]]).astype(np.float32) # x,y
src_pts = np.array([[19,175],[145,158],[176,284]]).astype(np.float32) #x,y

# calculate the affine transformation matrix
warp_mat = cv2.getAffineTransform(src_pts, dest_pts)

# get the registered source image
warp_dst = cv2.warpAffine(src, warp_mat, (dest.shape[1], dest.shape[0]))



fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,3)
ax[0].imshow(src,'gray')
ax[0].scatter(src_pts[:,0],src_pts[:,1],s=1,c='r')
ax[0].set_title('src')
ax[1].imshow(dest,'gray')
ax[1].scatter(dest_pts[:,0],dest_pts[:,1],s=1,c='r')
ax[1].set_title('dest')
ax[2].imshow(warp_dst,'gray')
ax[2].set_title('registered src')
plt.savefig('result.png')


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(dest,'gray')
ax.imshow(warp_dst,cmap='jet',alpha=0.5)
plt.savefig('overlayed_result.png')
# plt.show()
```

[image: result]

In order to calculate affine transformation matrix, you will need 3 matching points on both images. I highlighted the points I chose on both images. FYI, you can develop a way to automate finding matching points, let us know in your question if you need that.

[image: registered image overlay on the destination image]

Comment: I like your solution a lot! Indeed, in the end I will need to fit the dartboard per frame of my match / video. Manually clicking on three points per frame is unfeasible. Do you have a suggestion how we can do this automatically? Thank you for explaining how the affine-transformation works.

Comment: We can get one point by finding the intersection of all the lines, the bullseye / origin of the board

Comment: Happy to help! What is coming to my mind at the moment is that getting the most- left, right and bottom points of the dartboard. If you can make sure that you will cover the bottom part of dartboard in the video, you can get the corner points of the dartboard.The points would be `min_x`, `max_x` and `max_y` of the dartboard_pixels.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already done the image processing, I will take it from there. So just to be clear, this is the image I will be working with *(I cropped out the matplotlib axises, as I'm sure they aren't present in your actual image)*:

[image]

The concept is really simple:

1. Find the bounding box of the contour of the target.
2. With the bounding box, we can find the radius of the target by selecting the greatest among the dimensions *(width and height)* of the bounding box, and dividing it by 2.
3. With the radius of the target and the top-left corner coordinates of the target *(returned when finding the bounding box of the target)*, we can find the center of the target with the expressions `x + r` and `y + h - r`.

With the radius of the target, you can scale your theoretical target accordingly, and with the center of the target, you can draw your theoretical target at the right coordinates.

Here is how the code goes, where `Image.png` is the above image. Note that I only draw one circle onto the image; the rest of them can be drawn on using the same way, with just some added scaling:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("Image.png")
img_processed = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img_processed, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)[-2]

x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
r = max(w, h) // 2
center_x = x + r
center_y = y + h - r
cv2.circle(img, (center_x, center_y), r, (0, 255, 0), 5)
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:

[image]

Note that at this line:

```
cnt = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)[-2]
```

I am getting the contour with the second-greatest area, as the one with the greatest area would be the border of the image.